# Problem with post resquest in Angular with HttpClient

Tags: angular

after developed my spring boot application I need to do the call request on angular, the problem is the post request doesn't work (in postman everything works), my code in service is this:

```
saveData(data:Product){
    this.http.post<Product>(this.productsUrl+'/addProduct',data);
    
  }
```

while in the component.ts is this:

```
  this.service.saveData(this.product).subscribe((data: any)=>console.log(data), (error: any) => console.log('oops', error));
      console.log(this.product)
  }
```

firstly I tried to use this method above without the method "subscribe()", but it doesn't work, so I did my research and I read that I need the subscribe but when I added the method it give me this error:"Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'.ts(2339)",
Can somebody help me out?
ps: I'm new on angular, so I would like to know if there are other methods to do this call more efficiently/new.
Thanks to all.

Comment: You're not returning anything in `saveData`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return the http post result from `saveData` function and you can subscribe it. Return the result means return observable, so you can subscribe it.

```
saveData(data:Product){
    return this.http.post<Product>(this.productsUrl+'/addProduct',data);
    
  }
```

Comment: @PeterSmith Thanks, it working when I do the console.log() but when I sent to my spring application all parameter are null, Do you know how can I solve this?

Comment: inspect **network tab** in browser **developer tool** to check whether angular correctly sent to spring application. if there is the data that means the problem is with spring application and check if spring boot correctly binds it.

Comment: Does spring application binds parameter correctly when you send from postman.

Answer (score 0):

In my Spring Boot + Angular project I use the following working approach to make HTTP POST request.

On the server (Spring Boot) side:

```java
@RestController
@Transactional
public class CommonProductsController {

    @RequestMapping(path = "/products", method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<String> addNewProduct(@RequestParam("productTitle") String productTitle,
                                                @RequestParam("productDescription") String productDescription) {

        // here adding the product to db
                                                
    }
}
```

On the client (Angular) side:

```js
    const payload = new HttpParams()
    .set('productTitle', this.product.title))
    .set('productDescription', this.product.description);
    
    this.http.post('/products', payload).
      subscribe(
                (createdProductIdString) => {
                    // on success, processing the POST result, with returned string in createdProductIdString variable
                },
                (error) => {
                    // processing error
                }
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need http headers. Type this in your service.ts and change your save method

```
httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
  }

saveData(data:Product){
    this.http.post<Product>(this.productsUrl+'/addProduct',{data}, this.httpOptions);
    
  }
```

Also check if the data that you are passing in the parameter is an object with {}, because it is necessary in a post method. Let me know it works for you

Comment: yes, it worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're right when you said that you need to call subscribe.
The problem here is that you're not returning anything `saveData(data:Product)` method.
Here is how it should be written:

- Service side

```
saveData(data: Product): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.post<Product>(this.productsUrl + '/addProduct', data);
  }
```

- Component side

```
console.log(this.product)
this.service.saveData(this.product)
  .subscribe(data => console.log(data), error => console.log('oops', error));
```

That way, you'll be subscribing to the `Observable` returned by the `saveData(...)` method.

Comment: the problem is it always return an error now

Comment: Yes, it seems that the content-type was missing for the targeted API operation.